# Visual Studio fails to compile .NET MAUI project on Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui, aapt2

When I want to build my .NET MAUI Application on **Android**, I get this error:

```
1>        C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.4\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(212,3): error APT2000: The specified file cannot be found. (2).
1>        Processing A:\Documents\Semestre 5 Info\Recipes-MobileApp\CookUs\CookUs\obj\Release\net7.0-android\android\bin\packaged_resources JobId: 114 Exists: True JobWorked: False
1>        Link did not succeed. Deleting A:\Documents\Semestre 5 Info\Recipes-MobileApp\CookUs\CookUs\obj\Release\net7.0-android\android\bin\packaged_resources
1>      Done executing task "Aapt2Link" -- FAILED.
1>    Done building target "_CreateBaseApkWithAapt2" in project "CookUs.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>  Done executing task "CallTarget" -- FAILED.
```

I tried to reinstall Visual Studio a few times, to reinstall the Android SDK Components as well, but it fails everytime.

I couldn't find any informations about this.

---

**EDIT :**

As @Guangyu Bai - MSFT pointed out, the problem is caused by the path where the project is. My path contains spaces.

Comment: Does this project reference a vb.net project?

Comment: @tval no, the error happens when I try to build the .NET MAUI App template, there is nothing more in the code than files provided by the VS template.

Comment: Go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build And Run and change the build output verbosity to Detailed. It may give you a more detailed explanation why the project fails to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some information in the issue thread [Android - APT2000 build error when project path contains non-ASCII symbols](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6925) and [Application cannot be deployed on Android](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5642).

The build error is caused by putting project in a folder/directory containing some non-ASCII chars, like Czech alphabet (tested with á) breaks Android build. However, this does not affect any other C# projects.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the problem, I'm surprised I didn't think of that. I update my question to show clearly what was the problem.